# How to increase Timeout Limit

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, gpu

I am doing some GPU intensive work. It is not rare that my OPENGL will crash and with it the app using it. I get presented with an error message suggesting to fix this by increasing the timeout limit. How can I increase this limit?

[image]

**[Nvidia Link](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3007)**

Comment: Follow the links from the page to the Microsoft page that explains how to [change the timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Windows/Hardware/ff569918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the registry. The key you want to change is `KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\TdrLevel`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz there is not TdrLevel @ GraphicsDrivers

Comment: Right. You're supposed to add it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I can create several new types. I am not sure which one I should pick.  http://i.imgur.com/1JaKvr8.png

Comment: Did you read the link? Look under `ValueType`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Should the value be a HexaDecimal or Decimal?

Comment: Read the link. It the types and other information right there. Put it as decimal.